# How to make a background image to fit the size of the visible area on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When you open the site on a mobile device, you can see that the background image depends on the amount of content on the page, where there is more - the background image increases, where less - decreases. So, for example, when you open the navigation panel on a mobile device, you can see that the background increases dramatically, as the panel moves apart and more content becomes. How to make the background independent of the amount of content depends only on the viewing area.

What is at the moment in css and html

```
<body class="bg-image1">
body {  
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.bg-image1 {  
        background-image: url(path); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.bg-image1 {  
    background-image: url(путь); 
    height: 100vh; /* may need !important*/
    width: 100vw; /* may need !important*/
}
```

`vw` and `vh` stand for viewport width and viewport height respectively. So the image will be sized to the dimensions of the browser window.If the keyboard pops up at any point for interaction while the image is being displayed on mobile the viewport height will change and so will the height of your image. Just somethign to keep in mind.

Comment: Does not help.In the simulator of the mobile version in the browser, everything is fine, but when you go from the phone everything is different.

Comment: Do you have this line in your head tag? ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">```

Comment: Unfolded for example https://protected-ocean-52184.herokuapp.com/en/blog, go from your mobile device